# How to save file in a specific folder?

Tags: c#, epplus

I need to save the `.xlsx` generate by epplus to the `Desktop` so I did:

```
 var dlg = new SaveFileDialog
        {
           FileName = "FileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
           DefaultExt = ".xlsx",
           Filter = "Excel Sheet (.xlsx)|*.xlsx", 
           RestoreDirectory = true,
           InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        };
```

and then:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Create))
{
       package.SaveAs(fs);
}
```

where `package` is the `ExcelPackage package` of epplus.
This code should save the file to the desktop but I've two problems:

- The file is saved into the bin directory of my application
- The extension xlsx is missing when I specified that in the dlg definition

is that a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. There is some code between the show of the FileDialog and the call to write the file?

Comment: Have you checked the value of "dlg.FileName" when you create the file stream? Also - if you click on the cancel button - then "dlg.FileName" will be "FileName23-01-2018" without file extension - so will be saved exactly where & how you say. You need to click on Save - even though everything looks OK in the dialog.

Comment: I assume that you did call dlg.ShowDialog() somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code simply initialises the file dialog. You need to call "dlg.ShowDialog();" this will let you select a folder other than your initial folder. Ensure you click on the save button, if you click on cancel your initialised filename will not be modified with the path.

If you know you only want to save to the desktop you could use the Path.Combine method : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx

```
String FilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFo‌​lder.Desktop),
    "FileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".xlsx");
```